# Cannot connect to a server using proxy in Express JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, http-proxy

I have two servers running in my laptop- one for serving the front-end (app.js) and the other acts as an API server (apiServer.js). I am routing all my API calls to the API server using 'http-proxy' package from npm.

```
var express = require('express');


var logger = require('morgan');
/* var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser'); */

//PROXY
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

/* var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users'); */

var app = express();

// Proxy to API
const apiProxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({
  target: 'http://localhost:3001'
});

app.use('/api',function(req,res){
  apiProxy.web(req,res);
})
```

This is the error I get in the browser console:

## [image: Error refusing the connection attempt]

The command prompt where I run the app.js server crashes as soon as I load the website (But please note that it works just fine when I am connected to the Wi-Fi router). Here is screen capture:

[image: Error in server]

**One Possible Workaround**
It is working if I change target in the api settings in express to `http://127.0.0.1:3001`

[image]

I would be glad if somebody can still help me figure out why writing http://localhost:3001 doesn't work when I disconnect from the router.

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you started your express server.

Comment: @jfriend00 I have added the screen capture where the app server crashes throwing an error.

Comment: That screen capture has absolutely nothing to do with my comment, but I guess if it happens when you try to do a request of the server, then I guess your server is running.

Comment: ***Works just fine when connected to the WiFi router*** probably means you have a firewall issue.  When you're not on the WiFi router, you are presumably trying to get to your server from outside the firewall.

Comment: It sounds like you've got a problem with your networking settings, specifically something DNS related. Try using `127.0.0.1` (or some other suitable IP) instead of `localhost`, see if cutting out the DNS lookup fixes it.

Comment: @jfriend00 How do it rectify this? The same code seems to be working fine in another computer without connecting to the wi-fi-router.

Comment: @skirtle I tried 127.0.0.1:3000 but I am facing the same problem when I am disconnected from the wi-fi router.

Comment: I meant change the proxy to `127.0.0.1:3001`. The error `getaddrinfo ENOENT localhost:3001` would suggest it can't resolve `localhost`.

Comment: @skirtle Hi there! When I change the target in the http-proxy to http://127.0.0.1:3001, it works! Thanks. But i still wondering why http://localhost:3001, doesn't work.

Comment: No idea, you'll need to dig into your DNS configuration. This certainly isn't normal but at this point I don't think it's a question for SO.